# Automatically change div on mouseover and on timer

Tags: jquery, list, image, scroll

I'm a bit o a noob so any help would be great...

What I need to do is have it so that the div associated to a specific li can change on hover as well as automatically change on a timer so that it scrolls through the option.

here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#switches li").mouseover(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
            $("#slides div").hide();
            $("#slide" + $this.attr("id").replace(/switch/, "")).show();
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="featured">
<ul id="switches">
    <li id="switch1"><a href="activity_spa.html">Spa &amp; Wellness</a></li>
    <li id="switch2"><a href="#">Gala Venues</a></li>
    <li id="switch3"><a href="#">Dining</a></li>
    <li id="switch4"><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
    <li id="switch5"><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
    <li id="switch6"><a href="#">Team Building</a></li>
    <li id="switch7"><a href="#">Equestrian</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="slides">
    <div id="slide1"><img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide2" style="display:none;"><img src="images/image6.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide3" style="display:none;"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide4" style="display:none;"><img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide5" style="display:none;"><img src="images/image5.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide6" style="display:none;"><img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide7" style="display:none;"><img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you know that you can use `class="slide"` and `.index()` function?

Comment: sorry, like i said, i'm a litte new to this, can read and understand how some of the code works, but writing it isn't my strong point, would you have an example of what you were thinking...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your HTML a bit

```
<div id="featured">
<ul id="switches">
    <li id="switch_1"><a href="activity_spa.html">Spa &amp; Wellness</a></li>
    <li id="switch_2"><a href="#">Gala Venues</a></li>
    <li id="switch_3"><a href="#">Dining</a></li>
    <li id="switch_4"><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
    <li id="switch_5"><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
    <li id="switch_6"><a href="#">Team Building</a></li>
    <li id="switch_7"><a href="#">Equestrian</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="slides">
    <div id="slide_1">1<img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide_2" style="display:none;">2<img src="images/image6.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide_3" style="display:none;">3<img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide_4" style="display:none;">4<img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide_5" style="display:none;">5<img src="images/image5.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide_6" style="display:none;">6<img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="slide_7" style="display:none;">7<img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```

and your script

```
$(function () {
        $("#switches li").mouseover(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $("#slides div").hide();
        $("#slide_" + $this.attr("id").split('_')[1]).show();
        });
    });​
```

See a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/omogo4)** for the mouseover part.

See a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/omogo4/2)** for the timer part.

Comment: wow, thanks for getting back so quickly. Is it possible to have both funcations available... i.e. that is automatically changes on a timer as well as on hover of the list item. Thanks for your help so far and feel free to modify the code.